# Java - closing the UDP socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to simulate UDP using Java. I am sending a file from one host to another. This is the part of the receiver:

```
server.setSoTimeout(10000);     
while (true)
{
    try 
    {
        DatagramPacket received = new DatagramPacket(receivedData,receivedData.length);
        server.receive(received);
        out.write(received.getData());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }



    }
server.close();
```

This solution works, but I am not satisfied with it for some reason.

Sender sends all the packets and then it closes the DatagramSocket. Receiver gets all the packets and it terminates, but it terminates because of the timeout.

So if switch on my receiver and don't execute anything for 10 secs, my Receiver shuts off, so nothing is transmitted.

**Is there a way of terminating the loop without specifying the timeout?**

I was also wondering if there is a method for the other host to establish connection - something like ServerSocket.accept(), which basically waits for the other host to connect.But, I decided to use DatagramSocket and I can't find a solution to this issue.

**Does anybody know of a method that would perform this?**

Comment: Wait so are you wanting to keep the receiver switched on until the sender sends the file?

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol. There is no concept of a connection, only individual packets. There is also no guarantee these packets will arrive in the right order. It sounds like you want TCP, not UDP...

Comment: @RileyCarney well the idea is not use timeout, but to be able to indicate that all the bytes have been sent

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson So I assume that the first part is impossible to change, what about the second one?

Comment: If you still want to use UDP, have a look at [this tutorial](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Datagram (UDP) sockets are inherently connectionless. Closing a `DatagramSocket` does not have any effect which is visible to a remote system. It prevents an application from sending or receiving any further data on that socket, and frees up the port for use by other applications on the local system, but it does not cause any notification to be sent over the network.

If you want to notify the remote server that you are done sending data, you will need to send them a datagram notifying them of that.

If you are trying to transfer a file over UDP, keep in mind that UDP packets are not guaranteed to be received, nor are they guaranteed to be received in the same order they are transmitted! (That is, they may be dropped or reordered by the network.)

Comment: Yeah, I know that they are not guaranteed to arrive, so I was just wondering if there is a nicer way to write this part of the code.
What about part 2 of my question? Basically right now, I have 10 seconds to launch the sender, otherwise the connection expires. I know that in theory that should happen, but is there a way to start transmitting after Sender has been launched?

Comment: @JohnnyBravo If you want to be able to accept incoming connections, detect remote closure, and avoid packet loss and reordering, **use TCP sockets**. Their whole purpose is to solve these problems for you.